# Find image by ID in gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found this code, but this will not find image by ID, this code changes ID of all images in gallery

```
   $('#gallery').find('img').attr('id', 10);
```

I have also tried this but, yeah, I suck with Javascript

```
$('#gallery').getElementById(10);
```

Comment: `$('#gallery img[id="10"]');`

Comment: `$('#gallery').find('img#10')` wouldnt this do the job? **by the way i think it is not a good practice to start id with number** :)

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=find+element+by+attribute+with+jquery

Comment: if it's an id, it should be unique. So : `document.getElementById('10');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : You can use below jquery selector to find image inside gallery for `id="10"`

NOTE: - Id of img tag must be unique throughout your html dom, otherwise jquery will not give desired result.

```
var $imgWith10= $('#gallery img#10');
```

Comment: Title: _Find image by ID_

Comment: @RayonDabre, thanks for correction. my bad :(. I have updated my answer.